# Joda time's DateTime converted to java.util.Date strange issue

Tags: java, jodatime

I ran into a strange issue. Here is a snippet of code that describes it:

```
DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(0);

DateTime dt = new DateTime(dtz);

System.out.println(dt);
System.out.println(dt.toDate());
```

the output is:

```
2012-02-29T17:24:39.055Z
Wed Feb 29 19:24:39 EET 2012
```

I'm located UTC+2, but this action is supposed to create a java.util.Date object which is initialized for UTC time. What am I missing?

Comment: +1 This is a good question because the Javadocs for java.util.Date show a method called `getTimezoneOffset` despite the fact there is no corresponding setter nor constructor that takes in an offset.

Comment: @RayToal It is strange this is not fixed yet by Sun devs

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Date` doesn't *know* about a time zone at all - it only represents an instant in time (like Joda Time's `Instant` type). It's just a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. When you call `Date.toString()`, it *always* uses the system local time zone for converting that into a readable text form.

So there's nothing wrong here - just an expectations failure over *either* the meaning of `java.util.Date` *or* its `toString()` behaviour, or both.

(As an aside, prefer [`DateTimeZone.UTC`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#UTC) over creating your own.)

Comment: Thanks Jon! However using dt.toDate().getTime() is still my computer's local time. How do I get java.util.Date object with millis relevant to the time zone I specified?

Comment: @MartinAsenov: It's not clear what you mean. As I say, `java.util.Date` is *always* relative to the Unix epoch, which is January 1st 1970 midnight UTC.

Comment: Yes I know that. I guess my misunderstanding was that java.util.Date was relevant to timezone, so I expected new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(0)).toDate() to produce a Date object with millis 2 hours behind UTC+2. My intention was to somehow store user relevant time, but now I guess this is not needed at all :)

Comment: @MartinAsenov: Well it *might* be - it depends on context. For example, if you want to store a recurring meeting time, then the user time zone *does* matter, very much. If you're storing a log timestamp, then it doesn't.

Comment: The approach I'd take is to store system time and convert it during runtime to user specific time, because I also have the user's timezone stored. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 9):

To get a JDK `Date` that matches Joda's `DateTime`convert to `LocalDateTime`first.

As explained in the other answers, the time in milliseconds does not change depending on the timezone:

```
DateTime local = DateTime.now()
Date localJDK = local.toDate()
assert localJDK.getTime() == local.toInstant().getMillis()

DateTime differentTimeZone = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID('America/Chicago'))
Date localJDK2 = differentTimeZone.toDate()
assert differentTimeZone.toInstant().getMillis() == localJDK2.getTime()
assert localJDK.getTime() == localJDK2.getTime()
```

Converting a `LocalDateTime` to `Date` will change that:

```
Date differentTimeZoneJDK = differentTimeZone.toLocalDateTime().toDate()
assert localJDK.getTime() != differentTimeZoneJDK.getTime()
```

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour you want is this:

Date jdkDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(dt.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

Like Jon noted, JDK date is time zone agnostic. Hope this helps someone.