# Jodatime convert joda DATETIME to java.util.Date

Tags: java, jodatime

The offsetTimeZone method is converting from PST/PDT timezone to UTC timezone correctly, but we need the java.util.Date class,
But when i call the method dateTime.toDate(). The date converted back to  PST/PDT. How can we get the UTC date time in java.util.Date class?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date ="2014-06-28T05:00:00";

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date);
        DateTime dateTime = offsetTimeZone(localDateTime,DateTimeZone.getDefault().getID(),DateTimeZone.UTC.getID());
        System.out.println(dateTime.toString());   // output : 2014-06-28T12:00:00.000Z
        System.out.println(dateTime.toDate())  // output : Sat Jun 28 05:00:00 PDT 2014
}


public static DateTime offsetTimeZone(LocalDateTime date, String srcTz, String destTz) {
        DateTime srcDateTime = date.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID(srcTz));
        DateTime dstDateTime = srcDateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(destTz));
        return dstDateTime;
}
```

Comment: See the answer to a very similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9503824/1047448

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joda time's DateTime converted to java.util.Date strange issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503771/joda-times-datetime-converted-to-java-util-date-strange-issue)